# Rownum not working properly

Tags: oracle, rownum

I have two tables X and Y.
when I run below query for table X

```
select * from 
( select rownum as rn, A.* from X as A order by A.IDdesc) where rn between 0 
and 1000000;
```

I get result as

```
rn  Id  name 
1   1   xxx
2   2   yyy
3   4   zzz
```

but for Y table when same query is executed I get result as

```
select * from 
    ( select rownum as rn, A.* from Y as A order by A.IDdesc) where rn between 0 
    and 1000000;

rn  Id  name 
5   1   xxx
7   2   yyy
10  4   zzz
```

rn in Y table is getting some random numbers. Not able to understand this behavior. ny help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `ROWNUM` pseudo-column is added to the selected columns in the order Oracle retrieves the rows and then the `ORDER BY` clause is applied. What you appear to want is to order the rows first and then generate the `ROWNUM` against this ordering but that is not what your query will do.

For table X, it happens that Oracle retrieves the rows in the same order as the `id` column. However, for table Y, the rows are not retrieved in the same order as the `id` column so the `ROWNUM` is in the order the rows were retrieved and then a different ordering is applied so the `ROWNUM` values appear shuffled.

What you should do is to apply the `ORDER BY` before generating the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column so they are in-sync:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT rownum as rn,
         A.*
  FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   X
    ORDER BY ID desc
  ) A
)
WHERE  rn BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000;
```

Comment: So do we know why for table A it is retrieving in same order as id but same thing not happening for table B. Because with two subquery,performance would degrade.

Comment: @SYMA No, it would not degrade performance; you are not changing the operations Oracle is performing you are doing exactly the same operations in a different order.

Comment: ok.. instead of using two subquery can i use row_number. Would it improve performance?

Comment: @SYMA Try it and see - but I would not expect performance to improve; at best I would expect identical performance.